# bitcoin core, deleted receiving address?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Hi I set an address on bitcoin core and after I just downloaded it for mac. It was taking a crazy amount of time to synchronise which I realised was normal. I sent some $200 to the adress and whilst mucking around with the settings i hit the reset button which at the time I thought would fix the synchronisation issue. Anyway I've searched many .dat files and the receiving address is deleted from my bitcoin core app. Will I still receive my funds? If not, can I recover them?

Comment: Did you make a backup of the wallet, or make a note of the private key, before hitting that reset button?

Comment: If your node is syncing from scratch, the payment won’t be shown in the wallet until your node gets to that point in the network history. The ‘fix’ is likely to just wait until the sync is complete, and then all will be well. Your funds are at no risk in the meantime, as long as you keep the wallet file / backup safe.

Comment: Unless you deleted anything, the Settings Reset button won't change anything except some node settings. It does not effect any transactions in your wallet. It does not effect any of your addresses.

Comment: If , at some time in the past, you had changed the directory containing your wallet.dat file, resetting options might cause the wallet to not know where your wallet.dat file was.

Answer (score -1):

Did the same thing as you. In BitCoin Core, made a receive address.. then removed it. Then sent 5k worth of BTC to that removed address. Luckly.... Bitcoin Core has your back. Just don't close the wallet and wait till the transaction confirms, and sync the wallet 100%. It will eventually show incoming transaction and combine them into your main wallet. Search your wallet address you sent the transaction to with blockchain.com, see if its confirmed. Now its just a waiting game. Keeps your hair standing up

Comment: This makes no sense; you cannot delete receiving addresses in Bitcoin Core.